# How to filter records based on nested data using django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have this json response from my customer api based on django rest framework.

When I hit api

> http://localhost:8000/api/customers

I receive following response

```
[
 {
    'name': 'Daniel',
    'group': 'BK',
    'user_id': 102,
    'user_details': {
        'username': 'dan1',
        'active': true,
    }
 },
 {
    'name': 'John',
    'group': 'BK',
    'user_id': 103,
    'user_details': {
        'username': 'john1',
        'active': true,
    }
 }
]
```

Now I need to filter record whose username=john1, how do I do that?

I have tried using this in my customer viewset by defining filter backend

> filter_fields = ('user_details__username',)

and tried hitting the api as

> http://localhost:8000/api/customers?user_details__username=john1

but it gives error as

> 'Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet:
>   user_details__username

Its happening because user_details is not the field of my customer serializer, its basically SerializerMethodField which manipulates user information to display under customer api.

Here is my customer serializer

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user_details = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_serialized_target_object')

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'        

    def get_serialized_target_object(self, obj):
        usr_id = obj.user_id
        if usr_id:
            instance = User.objects.filter(pk=usr_id)
            if instance:
                instance = instance[0]
                return UserSerializer(instance=instance).data

        else:
            return None
```

and here is my viewset

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Customer.objects.all()
   serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
   filter_fields = ('user_details__username',)
```

Please help me how do I filter my record from customer api with username=john1

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `SerializerMethodField`.

Try the serializer below:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'active',)


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_details = UserSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then you can define your field as `filter_fields = ('user_details__username',)`